# How do I use a calculated column in a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out the total VOLUME of certain products in my database, I'm trying to list all products which have a volume of 3000 or more....

So I do a query like so:

```
SELECT (
products_width * products_height * products_length
) AS total_volume
FROM `price`
where total_volume > 3000
```

But I get an error stating that the column "total_volume" does not exist in the where clause, can you let me know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
SELECT (
    products_width * products_height * products_length
) AS total_volume
FROM `price`
HAVING total_volume > 3000
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT (
        products_width * products_height * products_length
    ) AS total_volume
    FROM `price`
)
WHERE total_volume > 3000
```

For the explanation, you can't use `total_volume` in the where clause directly, because it is created in the selection part of the query. `having` can be used in this case, or you can use a subquery.

Comment: i like the solution with HAVING, its very clean like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat the formula in your WHERE:

```
SELECT (products_width * products_height * products_length) AS total_volume
    FROM `price`
    where (products_width * products_height * products_length) > 3000
```

Comment: This will cause maintainability problems if the formula is subject to change, using `having` or a subquery is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: This solution is standard sql, so can be ported to other DBMS, though it haves maintainability problems as @krtek stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (
products_width * products_height * products_length
) AS total_volume
FROM `price`
HAVING total_volume >= 3000
```

that is - change WHERE to HAVING, that's all.

Comment: This won't give the wanted result.

Comment: Yes, of course Your are right... not "group by", but "HAVING"... where is my head!

Comment: It's updated now, however it's the same as Your answer, Krtek.